# Select rows with all childrens with only one status

Tags: sql, google-cloud-spanner

I look for some help with creation of SQL script.
I have such data:

table 'plans' with 'plan_id'
table 'transactions' with 'transaction_status'

plans and transactions are one-to-many, means that plans can have a lot of transactions

I want to read all plan_ids, but only such which has 100% of SUCCESS status

My real scenario is more complex than this, but I am left with such problem to solve now.

Comment: A [mcve] would make things much clearer.

Comment: What RDBMS used? Please set relevant tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below I post query example for PostgreSQL. You can adopt it to your version:

```
SELECT 
    plans.id, 
    COUNT(plan_id) all_transactions, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN success THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) success_transactions
FROM plans
JOIN transactions ON transactions.plan_id = plans.id
GROUP BY plans.id
HAVING COUNT(plan_id) = SUM(CASE WHEN success THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
;
```

[PostgreSQL fiddle](https://sqlize.online/sql/psql13/b24a2d7cea99018a8c4e4f1bca78d853/)